# Where can I get a list of all supported phonegap config.xml preferences?

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to find a list of all supported phone gap config.xml preferences. I can't seem to find one unifying place that is up-to-date and contains a list of all supported preferences.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and scanned the source code for iOS and Android to find all supported properties. I've published my work on [GitHub](https://github.com/kkirby/Cordova-Config-Properties).